# RTEMS compilation and installation error

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, rtems

I am trying to compile RTEMS on Ubuntu 14.04.

I am getting following error while trying run 'make':

Making all in tools/build
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/development/rtems/b-sis/tools/build'
make  all-am
make[2]: Entering directory`/home/user/development/rtems/b-sis/tools/build'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/development/rtems/b-sis/tools/build'
make[1]: Leaving directory`/home/user/development/rtems/b-sis/tools/build'
Making all in tools/cpu
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/development/rtems/b-sis/tools/cpu'
Making all in generic
make[2]: Entering directory`/home/user/development/rtems/b-sis/tools/cpu/generic'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory`/home/user/development/rtems/b-sis/tools/cpu/generic'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/user/development/rtems/b-sis/tools/cpu'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for`all-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/development/rtems/b-sis/tools/cpu'
make[1]: Leaving directory`/home/user/development/rtems/b-sis/tools/cpu'
Making all in testsuites/tools
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/development/rtems/b-sis/testsuites/tools'
Making all in generic
make[2]: Entering directory`/home/user/development/rtems/b-sis/testsuites/tools/generic'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory`/home/user/development/rtems/b-sis/testsuites/tools/generic'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/user/development/rtems/b-sis/testsuites/tools'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for`all-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/development/rtems/b-sis/testsuites/tools'
make[1]: Leaving directory`/home/user/development/rtems/b-sis/testsuites/tools'
Making all in sparc-rtems4.11/c
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/development/rtems/b-sis/sparc-rtems4.11/c'
Making all in .
make[2]: Entering directory`/home/user/development/rtems/b-sis/sparc-rtems4.11/c'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory`/home/user/development/rtems/b-sis/sparc-rtems4.11/c'
Making all in sis
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/user/development/rtems/b-sis/sparc-rtems4.11/c/sis'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target`all'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/development/rtems/b-sis/sparc-rtems4.11/c/sis'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory`/home/user/development/rtems/b-sis/sparc-rtems4.11/c'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

Here, is a list of steps I followed:

1. To install toold I used RSB and ran all commands listed here:
   https://devel.rtems.org/wiki/Developer/Tools/RSB
2. Then I have followed this list of commands: 
   https://devel.rtems.org/wiki/TBR/UserManual/Quick_Start

In this list, I have tried changing PATH variable = /development/rtems/4.11/bin=$PATH

Other then this everything is done by me following the commands listed here. I have done ./bootstrap -p as well.

Comment: YOu'll need to tell us about what you have done before this, which includes copy pasting all the commands you have been running. There's almost no information in what you have posted . e.g. have you created a proper gcc toolchain  ? Is the cross compiler in your PATH  ? What was the arguments you used to ./configure ?  Have you run ./bootstrap ? and so on.

Comment: I have edited the question. I used the same arguments provided in the link to configure.

Comment: Have you tried my blog https://learnsom2day.wordpress.com/2015/04/21/getting-started-with-rtems-hello-word/  ?

Comment: Could you delete all build folder, configure again, and post the errors? It could be a toolchain problem... if appear something like: checking for sparc-rtems4.11-gcc... no
configure: error: no acceptable cc found in $PATH

Answer (score 3):

You need the toolchain tools. Follow the [source builder tutorial](https://ftp.rtems.org/pub/rtems/people/chrisj/source-builder/source-builder.html) before compiling rtems.

1º Clone the tools

```
git clone git://git.rtems.org/rtems-source-builder.git
```

2º Check environment

```
${PATH-rtems-source-builder}/source-builder/sb-check
```

You must got:

```
RTEMS Source Builder - Check, 4.11 (6b0d76cc9b43 modified)
Environment is ok
```

If not, you need more dependencies.

3º Check the target arch you want:

```
cd ${PATH-rtems-source-builder}/rtems
../source-builder/sb-set-builder --list-bsets
${PATH-rtems-source-builder}/source-builder/sb-set-builder --log=l-sparc.txt --prefix=$HOME/development/rtems/4.11  4.11/rtems-sparc
```

You need to stay in ${PATH-rtems-source-builder}/rtems path, or the list won't be complete!

4º Configure

```
EXECUTABLE=$HOME/Repositories/git/rtems
TARGET=sparc-rtems4.11
PREFIX=${HOME}/opt/rtems
${EXECUTABLE}/configure --target=${TARGET} --enable-rtemsbsp=sis --enable-tests=samples --prefix=${PREFIX}
```

5º Execute boostrap

```
$HOME/Repositories/git/rtems/bootstrap
```

6º Go to your build path and compile & install

```
make
make install
```

Remember, you need the valid toolchain path in your environment variables.

In example:

```
export PATH=$HOME/development/rtems/4.11/bin:$PATH
```

If you don't want to do it everytime you restart, add that in your ~/.bashrc file. And use commando source to update the current terminal environment.

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: It looks like Step 4 skipped the step where you download RTEMS itself

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it cannot find binaries. 
That is probably because you haven't added them to your PATH environment variable.
You can do that with (use the correct path to the bin-directory of your setup)

```
export PATH=$HOME/development/rtems/compiler/4.12/bin:$PATH
```